# Changes to ICollection (many to many relationship) are not saved using ASP.NET Core and Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I feel like I'm completely desperate because I don't know how to fix this. Please help me if you can.

I am trying to build many-to-many relationship between my two models, "project" and "user". As in the typical examples, this relationship is implemented using `ICollection`.

My models - User:

```
namespace MLpolygon.Models
{
    public class user : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FName { get; set; }
        public string LName { get; set; }

        public ICollection<project> Projects { get; set; }

        public user()
        {
            Projects = new List<project>();
        }
    }
}
```

I use `AspNetCore.Identity` to work with user, but it seem not to be important, the changes are not saved in other model as well.

Project:

```
namespace MLpolygon.Models
{
    public class project
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public ICollection<user> Users { get; set; }
        public ICollection<calculator> Calculators { get; set; }

        public project()
        {
            Users = new List<user>();
            Calculators = new List<calculator>();
        }
    }
}
```

**Controller**: I am trying to create a relationship when adding a new project. I pass a new project object and the name of the user who created it to the function. All user names are unique.

Changes to the `ICollection` persist until you exit this function. But after this function exits, the changes disappear.

```
public class projectController : Controller
{
        private readonly MathLibContext _context;
        private readonly UserManager<user> _userManager;

        public projectController(MathLibContext context, UserManager<user> userManager)
        {
            _context = context;
            _userManager = userManager;
        }
        
        ...
        
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create([Bind("Id,Name")] project Project, string UserName)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                var result = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(UserName).Result;
    
                Project.Users.Add(result);
                _context.Add(Project);
                await _context.SaveChangesAsync();

                result.Projects.Add(Project);
                await _userManager.UpdateAsync(result);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return RedirectToAction(nameof(Add));
        }
}
```

My `DbContext` file:

```
public class MathLibContext : IdentityDbContext
{
    public MathLibContext(DbContextOptions<MathLibContext> options)
               : base(options)
    {
        Database.EnsureCreated();
    }

    public DbSet<calculator> Calculators { get; set; }
    public DbSet<project> Projects { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: `var result = _userManager.FindByNameAsync(UserName).Result;`?? Why? -> `var result = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(UserName);`. And "result" is not a proper name. If somebody later sees "var result" they have no idea what the object is, not even what type it is, unless they go back to the declaration.

Answer (score 0):

`Changes to the ICollection persist until you exit this function. But after this function exits, the changes disappear.` means the middle table(projectuser) did not add data successfully？

From your code, I find that your error may be in `MathLibContext`, Beacuse you custom identity, So you can't implement `IdentityDbContext` directly, You need wirte like this:

```
public class MathLibContext : IdentityDbContext<user>{xxxx}
```

Then in your `Startup.cs`, You may need to change too:

```
services.AddIdentity<user, IdentityRole>(xxxx)xxx;
```